# How to get a list of events shown on jquery-week-calendar with start/end times?

Tags: jquery, calendar

I'm using [jquery-week-calendar](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) and want to post all the calendar events to the server *after* the user is done adding/moving/deleting them in the browser. That means I will need a list of all the events currently shown on the calendar with start/end days+times (something similar to [getTimeslotTimes](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/blob/master/jquery.weekcalendar.js#L441)). Any help would be appreciated, see below on my attempts to get the data.

Thanks, Chirag

I tried `$("#calendar").find('.wc-cal-event')` but it doesn't include the days and times as shown here:

```
<div class="wc-cal-event ui-corner-all ui-resizable ui-draggable" style="line-height: 15px; font-size: 13px; top: 480px; height: 539px; display: block;"><div class="wc-time ui-corner-top">08:00 am to 04:59 pm<div class="wc-cal-event-delete ui-icon ui-icon-close"></div></div><div class="wc-title">Open hours</div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s">=</div></div>
```

Also  `$("#calendar").data().events` returns the handlers only:

```
click [Object { type="click",  guid=2,  handler=function(),  more...}]
mouseout [Object { type="mouseout",  guid=4,  handler=function(),  more...}]
mouseover [Object { type="mouseover",  guid=3,  handler=function(),  more...}]
remove [Object { namespace="weekCalendar",  type="remove,  guid=1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the source contains a `serializeEvents()` function, as defined below:

```
serializeEvents: function() {
    var self = this;
    var calEvents = [];

    self.element.find('.wc-cal-event').each(function() {
       calEvents.push($(this).data('calEvent'));
    });
    return calEvents;
},
```

Alternatively, it looks as though the information about the event is stored inside the `calEvent` data key, so I guess you could write your won function along the lines of:

```
$('.wc-cal-event').each(function() {  
    // Work here with $(this).data('calEvent');
});
```